# Find the max(date) from two tables in the most efficient manner

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, performance, query-performance

I have two large tables containing a common value `ContactReference`, and two `DateTime` fields (amongst a lot of other fields).  One table for `Contact` and one for `ContactAddress`.

I am trying to find an efficient query to find, for a `ContactReference` AND between two dates, the `MAX(date)` when one of the values was changed.

i.e. Regardless whether it was the `Contact` or `ContactAddress` that changed between the dates, when did that happen?

I have tried:

#### `ROW_NUMBER`

```
SELECT
            c.ContactReference AS ContactReference
          , c.EditDate AS EventDateTime
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY
                                    c.ContactReference
                                ORDER BY
                                    c.EditDate DESC
                              ) AS rn
        FROM
            dbo.Contact AS c
```

#### `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT
            *
        FROM
            contactCTE c
        WHERE
            c.rn = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            contactAddressCTE ca
        WHERE
            ca.rn = 1
```

With CTEs and without.

#### `INNER JOINs`

Putting the `BETWEEN` predicate at the end, in the first select, after the union, etc. etc.

`ROW_NUMBER` was the worst at 21 seconds.

ALL of the others come back in 7 seconds...and the execution plan is pretty similar whatever I try (CTE is marginally less expensive).

The above are examples of what I have tried, not the full SQL which would be pages of "tried this, tried that".

Any ideas how I can speed this up?

There are indexes on the "key" value (`ContactReference`) in both tables. I thought of a composite index on `(ContactReference, EditDate)`, but there are around 2mn rows in `Contact` and 25mn in `Address` and they both get edited regularly (by external processes) and I'm concerned about the size and performance hit of maintaining both indexes.

Comment: The query (or queries?) in the question appear to be incomplete. Please edit and post the whole queries you have tried. We don't mind pages of code ;) Please also add table definitions (CREATE TABLE statements)

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example) to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried anything like this?

Your tables (small subset!):

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 (date_1 DATE);
CREATE TABLE table_2 (date_2 DATE);
```

Data (a sample):

```
INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES ('2013-05-05'), ('2002-02-02'), ('2001-01-01');
INSERT INTO table_2 VALUES ('2012-05-05'), ('2004-04-02'), ('2006-01-01');
```

The query:

```
SELECT MAX(date_1) AS the_date FROM
(
  SELECT date_1 FROM table_1 -- AS the_date
  UNION
  SELECT date_2 FROM table_2 -- AS the_date
) AS my_tab;
```

Result:

```
           the_date
05/05/2013 00:00:00
```

I imagine that with an index on your `DATE` field, this would be about as good as it gets? I may have missed something, because this seems fairly simple - but who knows? Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=1d3365f41ee178472451140302fc5c43).

You could also try (something like):

```
SELECT MAX(max)  FROM
(
  SELECT MAX(date_1) FROM table_1  -- AS the_date
  UNION
  SELECT MAX(date_2) FROM table_2  -- AS the_date
) my_tab;
```

Now, this works under PostgreSQL 10 (fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=9d0cc5c04fb380f45fc22775860b2c7e)), but I can't for the life of me get it working in SQL Server 2014 - some sort of column naming problem (be grateful for an explanation). I've no way of testing for efficiency at my end, since I only have access to SQL Server through the fiddles.